# OpenAI API showing error in "reply=chat.choices[0].message.content" not recognizing "choices[0].message.content"

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api

```py
import openai
import Api_key
messages=[{"role": "system", "content": "You are kind helpful assistant"}]

while True:
    msgFromUser=input("User : ")
    if msgFromUser:
        messages.append({"role": "user", "content": msgFromUser})
        chat=openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=messages
        )
    reply=chat.choices[0].message.content #showing error in this line
    print(f"ChatBot: {reply}")
    messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": reply})
```

Why isn't my code running?

> user:hi
> chatBot:hello!

Comment: Did you try to either `console.log` or see in a debugger what `chat` is?

Comment: It looks like you are using Python.
According to the [package documentation][1] your code should be running fine.

I tested it line by line in a notebook without issue. The chatbot answered the user input and kept the conversation going alternating between asking for user input and answers from the bot.

Do you see any error?
Does it stop after a certain number of loops?


  [1]: https://github.com/openai/openai-python

Comment: The actual error would be really helpful. Ah yes, an abandoned question. :ı

Answer (score 0):

openai.api_key = 'sk-ENTER YOUR API KEY'

use this line and use api key to solve the error